# How to update code for use on 64-bit systems?

Tags: vba

I recently changed Windows.

When I run my VBA code I get the following message:
[image]

```vb
 'Place this code in a Module
 
Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
```

Comment: "Message"? This is some simple VBA code used to find a specific window handler. Where do you see this?

Comment: Did you switch to 64-bit Office?  You will need to update the API declarations.  https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit

Comment: Yes i switched to 64 bit office.

Comment: try to put a ptrsafe key, like --> Private Declare ptrsafe Function <--

Comment: Solved, thanks Luis, i added ptrsafe before Function.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a precompile If statement to work with Win 32 and 64.

The code below will make this work in Windows 32 and 64 bit systems.

```
Option Explicit
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "USER32" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "USER32" _
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function SetWindowLongA Lib "USER32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: thanks Ricardo, your reply helped too !